# Changing the icon in a button based off of MediaPlaybackState

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a MediaPlayerElement and the following class to control it:

```
class MediaPlayer : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            private MediaPlaybackState _State;
            public MediaPlaybackState State
            {
                get
                {
                    return _State;
                }
                set
                {
                    _State = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
            public BitmapImage AlbumArt;
            public string Title;
            public string Subtitle;
            private MediaPlayerElement mediaPlayer;

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

            public void PlayerStateChanged(MediaPlaybackSession session, object sender)
            {
                State = session.PlaybackState;
            }
            public void SetMediaElement(MediaPlayerElement param)
            {
                mediaPlayer = param;
            }
            public void PlayFromSearchResult(SearchResult result)
            {
                AlbumArt = new BitmapImage();
                AlbumArt.UriSource = new Uri(result.StationImage);
                Title = result.StationName;
                Subtitle = result.Subtext;
                PlayFromRemoteM3U(result.StreamURL);
            }
            public void Pause()
            {
                mediaPlayer.MediaPlayer.Pause();
            }
            public void Play()
            {
                mediaPlayer.MediaPlayer.Play();
                mediaPlayer.MediaPlayer.PlaybackSession.PlaybackStateChanged += PlayerStateChanged;
            }
            public async void PlayFromRemoteM3U(string url)
            {
                    --SNIP--
                    mediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri(streamDownloadUrl));
                    Play();
                }
            }
            protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));

        }
```

I would like to have a play/pause button that changes it's content based on the current player state, I'm currently debugging with a TextBlock to display the current state:

`<TextBlock x:Name="media_player_state" x:FieldModifier="public" FontSize="20" Text="{x:Bind MediaPlayerInstance.State, Mode=OneWay}">Play</TextBlock>`

When I run the application and start a stream so the state changes, I get the following error:
`The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))`

I want to know if there I am trying to accomplish this the right way or how to fix this.

Thanks

Comment: The error you meet happens when some methods that need to be called in UI Thread are called in a non-UI Thread. I'd suggest you do not use the binding first and run the app to check if this error still exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're calling it from another thread, you need to use a dispatcher

```
public void PlayerStateChanged(MediaPlaybackSession session, object sender)
{
   DispatcherHelper.ExecuteOnUIThreadAsync(() =>
   {
      State = session.PlaybackState;
   });
}
```

please note 2 things:

1- DispatcherHelper is part of the windows community toolkit nuget package (https://www.nuget.org/profiles/Microsoft.Toolkit)

2- DispatcherHelper will be deprecated in favor of the better DispatcherQueueHelper in the 7.0 release

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not setting the state everytime you Play() or Pause().
Change the _State value and then use OnpropertyChanged("State")

Comment: Think that's handled in the callback to `PlayerStateChanged` that's updating the State which then will notify the property changed in the setter. Info is missing here about what's throwing the thread exception. Seems like something needs to be handed back to the UI thread?